# How to create a second create method in Ruby on Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Survey class and typical CRUD methods, including one create method.
I want to create a second create method named create_pre, which does more nuanced survey creation.

Here is my code:

```
  def create #old create survey method
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@survey, :notice => 'Survey was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @survey, :status => :created, :location => @survey }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @survey.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the new one:

```
  def create_pre #new create survey method
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @survey.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@survey, :notice => 'Survey was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @survey, :status => :created, :location => @survey }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @survey.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

but when I am trying to use the new one from the console, I am getting an error:

```
 s = Survey.create_pre name: 'Levi\'s Pre survey', intervention_id: 165242, template_id: 3
NoMethodError: undefined method `create_pre' for Survey (call 'Survey.connection' to establish a connection):Class
Did you mean?  create
    from /home/levi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
```

Don't know how to fix this?

When I am calling create, a survey gets created and saved in the db.

```
irb(main):022:0* s = Survey.create name: 'Levi\'s Pre survey', intervention_id: 165242, template_id: 3
  SQL (5.1ms)  USE [evrrprod2012]
  SQL (4.1ms)  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  SQL (6.0ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [surveys] ([name], [intervention_id], [template_id], [created_at], [updated_at]) OUTPUT INSERTED.[id] VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)', N'@0 nvarchar(4000), @1 int, @2 int, @3 datetime, @4 datetime', @0 = N'Levi''s Pre survey', @1 = 165242, @2 = 3, @3 = '02-25-2016 13:09:15.37', @4 = '02-25-2016 13:09:15.37'  [["name", "Levi's Pre survey"], ["intervention_id", 165242], ["template_id", 3], ["created_at", Thu, 25 Feb 2016 18:09:15 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Thu, 25 Feb 2016 18:09:15 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (2.9ms)  COMMIT TRANSACTION
=> #<Survey id: 40, template_id: 3, name: "Levi's Pre survey", created_at: "2016-02-25 18:09:15", updated_at: "2016-02-25 18:09:15", intervention_id: 165242, created_by: nil, skip_reason: nil, skipped: nil, label: nil, note: nil, parent_id: nil>
```

Same attempt when using create_pre fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Survey.create_pre` is trying to call a class method on the `Survey` class, which by convention will be a model, not your controller.

#### Update

Just addressing the new comment and addition from OP to their question.

The `Survey.create` method you've added is nothing to do with the `SurveysController#create` method you're showing earlier in your question.

The one you're showing is a controller instance method that you've defined yourself, in your controller, to handle an incoming request. The one you're calling in your console, `Survey.create` is an `ActiveRecord::Base` class method that's available in your `Survey` model because it inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

The `create` method in `SurveysController` has nothing to do with the `Survey.create` method you're able to call in your console, and likewise the new `create_pre` method you've added to `SurveysController` cannot be called on the `Survey` model.

Comment: That call is for survey's intervention and is defined in interventions.rb (a model). However even if I am removing create_pre entirely and I am duplicating exactly create as create_pre, I am still getting the same error: NoMethodError: undefined method `create_pre'.

Comment: The `create_pre` that you show above is obviously a controller method, it will be defined in something like `app/controllers/surverys_controller.rb` - I don't know why you think it has anything to do with either the survey or intervention models.

Comment: The create method is in the same controller. Both methods, create and create pre are in the same surveys_controller.rb . I wll edit the question to eliminate any confusions with other things like interventions.

Comment: Your question didn't contain anything confusing about interventions, it was your *comment* to my answer where you started speaking about interventions. So anyway, as you say now, both `create` and `create_pre` methods are *instance* methods on `SurveysController` and yet in your console you're calling `Survey.create_pre` - ie. as I said in my answer, you're trying to call a *class method* on `Survey`!

Comment: I will edit again to add the successful result when calling Survey.create !